# Line appearing below the chart in plotly (Using Layout - Shapes)

Tags: r, charts, plotly

I'm trying to make a horizontal donut chart with a line indicating my value.
Something like this:[image]

But in my code the line is below the chart. Like this:
[image]

Heres the code:

```
  a <- list(
  showticklabels = F,
  autotick = F,
  showgrid = F,
  zeroline = F)
      

  b <- list(
    xref = 'paper',
    yref = 'paper',
    x = 0.5,
    y = 0.5,
    showarrow = FALSE,
    text = '')
  
  base_plot <- plot_ly(
    type = "pie",
    values = c(50, 7.14, 7.14, 7.14, 7.14, 7.14, 7.14, 7.14),
    labels = c("-", "0", "20", "40", "60", "80", "100", "150"),
    rotation = 90,
    direction = "clockwise",
    hole = 0.4,
    textinfo = "none",
    textposition = "outside",
    hoverinfo = "none",
    domain = list(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1)),
    marker = list(colors = c('#FFFFFF', '#440832', '#80180e', '#a52223', '#c0291b', '#f5c142', '#6aca3c', '#3980de')),
    showlegend = F
  ) %>% 
    layout(
      shapes = list(
        list(
          type = 'lines',
          x0 = 0.5,
          x1 = 0.5,
          y0 = 0.5,
          y1 = 1,
          xref = 'paper',
          yref = 'paper',
          fillcolor = '#000000',
          layer = "above"
        )
      ),
      xaxis = a,
      yaxis = a,
       annotations = b
)
```

Looking at the Plotly documentation the parameter [layer = "above"] should resolve my problem, but it isn't working. How do I make the line appear above the chart?

Comment: this will help you: https://plot.ly/r/gauge-charts/

Comment: Hello, I've tried this one, actually I used as base to create my chart. But in the example it's using SVG path and I would like to use lines instead of SVG :(

Comment: Your code works correctly in my R 3.5.0. with plotly_4.7.1.9000. I get the line above the chart, as expected. Try to install the development version of plotly: `devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marco Sandri told

> Your code works correctly in my R 3.5.0. with plotly_4.7.1.9000. I get the line above the chart, as expected. Try to install the development version of plotly: devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly").